# regex for text between two text

Tags: regex

I am trying to apply a regex (.net) to extract the first, last, and middle names from the following (the data has been anonymized):

```
19DCSSMITHDACJOHNDADADBD12345616DBB
```

The last name regex

```
(?<=DCS)\w+(?=DAC)
```

correctly returns "SMITH", and the middle name regex

```
(?<=DAD)\w+(?=DBD)
```

correctly returns "A", but the first name regex

```
(?<=DAC)\w+(?=DAD)
```

is returning "JOHNDA" instead of "JOHN" because the middle name is "A" making there be a DADAD.

How can I fix the first name regex to stop at the first DAD?

Comment: Do you have to use a single regex for each part you wish to retrieve? A single regex capturing the different parts into capturing groups would be more efficient, robust, and easy to maintain

Comment: Unfortunately I do have to use a single regex for each part

Comment: You could use lazy quantifiers for your current problem, `\w+?` instead of `\w+`, but then you'll fail to retrieve the whole name when it contains the delimiter (last name BORDAC would be captured as BOR)

Comment: actually, although I do have to use a single regex, I can specify the capture group.  So I could use "DCS(\w+)DAC(\w+)DAD(\w+)DBD" and specify group 1 for last name, group 2 for first name, and group 3 for middle

Comment: that would work as well, capturing less than the full name is better than more since I'm using the result in a db query

Comment: Go with the single regex (and try to match from the start of the string up to its end, anchoring the regex), the more of the string you match the more sure you are you actually retrieved what you meant to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
(?<=DAC)\w+?(?=DAD)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/AiK8LQ/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DAC                      'DAC'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+?                     word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the least amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DAD                      'DAD'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 1):

You may just avoid lookarounds and use 3 capture groups:

```
DCS(\w+)DAC(\w+)DAD(\w+)DBD
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/g8RHo8/1)

This captures `SMITH`, `JOHN` and `A` in 3 separate capture groups.